# UPS verse UPS XML

Tags: shipping-methods, enterprise-1.13, ups

We switched to using UPS XML recently in Magento EE 1.13. How ever we noticed that UPS "Next Day Air Saver" is no longer available?

Is there an update for this or is this a setting we have to get from UPS?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code I found `app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php`

```
            // Shipments Originating in United States
            'Shipments Originating in United States' => array(
                '01' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Next Day Air'),
                '02' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Second Day Air'),
                '03' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Ground'),
                '07' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express'),
                '08' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Expedited'),
                '11' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Standard'),
                '12' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Three-Day Select'),
                '14' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.'),
                '54' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express Plus'),
                '59' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Second Day Air A.M.'),
                '65' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Saver'),
            ),
```

It isn't there, maybe something to file a bugfix for in you Magento Entreprise dashboard. I don't really know why it is like this, but it is to provide some feedback where the source originates.